# Select rows from a data frame using an array in R

Tags: r, select, row, dataframe

I wish to select a set of rows from a data frame in R given multiple parameters.  Normally this could be done using an OR statement, however the values are housed in an array.  I am querying them as such (and with no luck):

Some data to get us rolling:

```
x = array(c(1,2,3),c(5,5))
y=c(1,2)
```

The command I'm presently using is (filtering by column 1):

```
x[x[,1] == y, ]
```

The above command yields this error:

```
Warning message:
In x[, i] == y :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Which makes sense.  I just don't know how to get around it.

What I am looking for is:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    3    2    1    3
[2,]    2    1    3    2    1
[3,]    1    3    2    1    3
[4,]    2    1    3    2    1
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `%in%`.

```
> x[x[,1] %in% y, ]

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    1    3    2    1    3
# [2,]    2    1    3    2    1
# [3,]    1    3    2    1    3
# [4,]    2    1    3    2    1
```

As @Ricardo said under comment, to explain better as to why this is happening. When you equate `x[,1]` to `y`, you get:

```
x[,1] == y
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Since `y` is `1,2` it just equates that to `x[, 1]` and since both of them match, returns TRUE. Since the length of output must equal `length(x[, 1])`, the rest is "recycled" (y = 1, 2, 1 against x = 3, 1, 2) which results in FALSE. But now, if you use `x[., ]` to fetch the rows, only the first two values are TRUE. So, only the first two will be picked. Using `%in% results in:

```
x[,1] %in% y
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Which is what you expect.

Comment: great!  But to clarify, if two vectors are different sizes, the rest are *not* filled in as FALSE. The shorter is recycled. It just so happens in this example that there are no further positive matches.  (ie what is actually happening at the end is a comparison: `c(3 == 1, 1==2, 2==1)`, which are all FALSE.

Comment: I elaborated on this below. -RS

Comment: Yes, sorry for the bad writeup again. I've added the `recycling` part instead of just saying they're FALSE.

Comment: Thanks for the extra explanation.  Very helpful

Comment: (+1) @RicardoSaporta, thanks for the follow up. Just noticed.

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Arun's answer, if the two vectors being compared are of different sizes, `R` wil **recycle** the shorter one so that `R` is comparing two vectors of the same size, and then it makes a **pair-wise** comparison.  (ie  compares the first element of each vector, then the second element of *eac* vector, etc).

It does **not**, for example, compare the first element of vector one against *all* of the elements in vector two. (for that you need `%in%` as @Arun mentioned)

For example, take a look at the following. 
The first two examples yield equivalent output

```
> c(0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2) == c(1, 2)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

> c(0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2) == c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE

The comparisons being made are:

 #  element#   LHS     RHS   areEqual
 #     1.       0       1      FALSE   <~~ Notice that the '0' from LHS is being compared with the '1' from RHS
 #     2.       1       2      FALSE  
 #     3.       2       1      FALSE
 #     4.       0       2      FALSE
 #     5.       1       1       TRUE
 #     6.       2       2       TRUE
```

Here is another example, with the LHS "shifted" relative to the previous example.

```
> c(1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0) == c(1, 2)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Note what happens when the shorter vector is not an exact multiple of the longer element. 
(ie, 2 does not go into 7).
The recylcing still occurs, but a portion of the shorter vector gets cropped from the last recycle.
`R` gives us a warning, just in case we did not expect them to be different sizes

```
> c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 0) == c(1, 2)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
Warning message:
In c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 0) == c(1, 2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Notice that it does not matter if the longer vector is on the RHS or LHS; the recycling works just the same

```
> c(1, 2) == c(1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```